# When closing old unanswered but upvoted questions, consider downvoting down to zero (right?)

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, votes, old-posts

Some of us are actively scavenging old questions and voting to close some of them as off-topic or unclear. This is great. If such a question has zero score, then it will be automatically deleted shortly after getting closed. However, if it has a positive score, it will not. Hence, if you think a question is bad, consider downvoting it as well.

Three examples that I had in the review queue right now one after another:

- [Seasonal Unit Root](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18473)
- [Locating a set of 5 geometrically constrained points within a cloud of points](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62134)
- [How to compute the probability that there is no difference between matched pairs](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74120)

All three are from 2011--2013. All three had +1 score. All three were found by @Kjetil who voted to close, and all three got closed with me casting the last vote. However, nobody downvoted them until I did.

What do you think?

Comment: To find old closed posts which (maybe) needs downvoting, use a search like `* closed:yes duplicate:no score:1 created:..2016` (where * is some search term(s)).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I basically agree with @amoeba's reasoning. The rest of this post is just elaboration.

As a matter of expedience, I think it makes sense to down-vote **old** questions (posted more than 12 months ago) which are off-topic, low-quality, or too broad to be answerable. It takes five people to vote to close a question, but just one person to move a question from 0 score to -1 score. As a matter of policy, SE deletes questions with negative score and no answers (or no answers with positive score) on approximately a weekly basis. On a less-frequent basis, 0-score questions are deleted under certain conditions. It's not a very efficient use of resources to have 5 people involved in closing a *years-old* question that asks for code, or "which test do I run?".

There's a reason that I advocate down-voting **old** questions specifically. The closure queues are primarily oriented around giving recently-active users useful feedback on how to improve a question. **Recent** questions which might be off-topic or otherwise unsuitable should absolutely be placed in the queue so that active users can receive that feedback and improve their questions. **We want to encourage new users.**

In all cases, duplicate questions should be closed as duplicates, so that our canonical content is ranked highly by search engines & are otherwise more visible to users.

---

My overall philosophy regarding down-voting is that it should be **rare** and **carefully considered**. This is because down-voting is pretty strong negative feedback.

- Down-voting that is not accompanied by a considered request for clarification or other context is inscrutable to the person who received the down-vote.
- Because [we need more answers, and therefore more answer-writers](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix), I am particularly cautious about down-voting of new users. Today's new user could be tomorrow's high-value contributor.