# What to do with a question which asks about R packages and how to fit RBF networks

Tags: discussion, on-topic, closing-questions, exact-duplicates, new-users

This question

[How to fit a RBF network in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/367997/58675)

asks an off-topic question (which R package to use to fit RBF networks) and a question which, while on-topic, is very likely a duplicate. Should I close or flag as duplicate? Ask him to eliminate the part about R packages, then close as duplicate? He's a new user, so I'd like to cut him some slack...

Comment: If it's a duplicate, I'd mark it as a duplicate, it's far more helpful then closing as off-topic. If it's not a duplicate and the non-software part can be answered, you can answer it mentioning briefly that you'd focus on the non-software part because we're not a software help list.

Comment: Thanks @Tim, that's very rational. I'll follow your advice. Of course only the non-software part would be a duplicate, thus I'll both flag and leave a comment explaining that the software part is OT.

Comment: I agree w/ @Tim. If you find a suitable duplicate target, leave a comment & flag the thread. In the interim, I closed it as off topic (& too broad).

Comment: @Tim: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From Tim's comment:

**If it's a duplicate**, then mark it as a duplicate. That is far more helpful than closing as off-topic.

**If it's not a duplicate** and the non-software part can be answered, then you can answer it, mentioning briefly that you will focus on the non-software part because we're not a software help list.