# Has the rate of unanswered questions risen in the last year?

Tags: discussion, unanswered-questions

Disclaimer: I haven't been very active the last year, and I didn't perform a statistical analysis on actual CV traffic data, thus I may definitely be wrong. However, I have the impression that the number of unanswered questions has risen with respect to last year. It has always been a sizeable fraction of the total questions, but now it seems larger to me. Am I correct? I guess it's pretty normal for a mature Q&A site. At some point, the site starts to become more of a database of good questions & answers, rather than a place where most of the new questions are answered (or closed as dupes).

Comment: We have several data-oriented answers to this question here, so perhaps reprising these analyses could provide a quantitative answer: https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5325/we-have-a-very-large-widening-gap-between-questions-and-answers-how-do-we-fix/5326#5326 Keep in mind that due to how the Roombas work, there will tend to be a larger fraction of unanswered questions in the past 12 months compared to posts older than 1 year.

Comment: The OP doesn't have to produce numbers, and nor does anyone else, and I am not inclined to work at it either. But unless _someone_ does produce numbers, I have to suggest that there is no point in a question that just invites speculation.

Comment: The pattern of the plot in Sycorax's post (linked above) continues -- smoothing the data from the query by eye since then, broadly it seems like raw answer rates have slowed since early 2017 and continue to do so (I can't discern any clear impact on that trend since Sept/Oct last year, though a more careful analysis might reveal a small effect), while questions have been more or less stable (/slowly growing) over the last year. The gap is wider. Losing active answerers has continued and it sure won't help in the long term but there didn't seem to be any instantaneous impacts.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica thanks, your comment is the answer I was looking for.